# How do I specify a field name for a wrapped tuple in Pig?

Tags: schema, apache-pig

I have a tuple with schema `(a:int, b:int, c:int)` stored in alias `first`.  I want to convert each tuple to have a new relation `second` with schema like this:

```
(d: (a:int, b:int, c:int))
```

Basically, I've wrapped my initial tuple in another tuple and named the field.  This is in preparation for a `cross` operation where I want to cross two relations but keep each one in a named field.

Here is what I would expect it to look like, except there's an error:

```
second = FOREACH first GENERATE TOTUPLE(*) AS (d:tuple);
```

This errors out too:

```
second = FOREACH first GENERATE TOTUPLE(*) AS (d:tuple (a:int, b:int, c:int));
```

Thanks!
Uri

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about:

```
second = FOREACH first GENERATE TOTUPLE(*) AS d;
describe second;
second: {d: (a: int,b: int,c: int)}
```